# How to enable NFC in aosp android

Tags: android, nfc, android-source, nfc-p2p, lib-nfc

I have aosp 10 source code but when I run the build image by flashing, I am not able to find NFC in connected device.

How to check NFC chip integrated in device? Is there any command to check in terminal?

As per device manufacture, they said they integrated NFC chip. But how to check whether it has been integrated?

I checked with following command:

```
console:/ $ dumpsys nfc
Can't find service: nfc
console:/ $
console:/ $ service call nfc 6
service: Service nfc does not exist
10|console:/ $ 


 30|console:/ $ svc nfc enable          
[  435.500512] type=1400 audit(1661508604.455:14): avc: denied { getattr } for comm="webview_zygote" path="/data/data/com.android.webview" dev1
[  435.618730] type=1400 audit(1661509016.541:15): avc: denied { read } for comm="app_process" name="u:object_r:device_config_runtime_native_b1
[  435.647432] type=1400 audit(1661509016.541:15): avc: denied { read } for comm="app_process" name="u:object_r:device_config_runtime_native_b1
[  435.672860] type=1400 audit(1661509016.541:16): avc: denied { open } for comm="app_process" path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:device_con1
[  435.731763] type=1400 audit(1661509016.541:16): avc: denied { open } for comm="app_process" path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:device_con1
[  435.762134] type=1400 audit(1661509016.541:17): avc: denied { getattr } for comm="app_process" path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:device_1
Got a null NfcAdapter, is the system running?
console:/ $ [  435.937225] type=1400 audit(1661509016.541:17): avc: denied { getattr } for comm="app_process" path="/dev/__properties__/u:obje1
[  435.971312] type=1400 audit(1661509016.541:18): avc: denied { map } for comm="app_process" path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:device_conf1
^C
130|console:/ $ svc nfc disable                                                
Got a null NfcAdapter, is the system running?
console:/ $
```

Also I checked in device/kernel/nfc.

How to enable NFC to display in connected devices in Settings? or how to check if NFC chip available in device?